# React state not updating immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

The React state is not updating immediately. I want to update the state immediately on the press of Play button.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";
export default function Play() {
  const [player, setPlayer] = React.useState(1);
  function nextPlayer() {
    setPlayer(2);
    updateValue();
  }
  function updateValue() {
    if (player == 1) {
      console.log("player 1");
    } else if (player == 2) {
      console.log("player 2");
    }
  }
  return <Button title="play" onPress={nextPlayer} />;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are supposed to do?

Comment: You can format your code using either `\`\`\`multiline-code-here\`\`\`` or a single item by `\`putting them inside ticks\``. It really helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `updateValue` is created in the Closure that contains the "old value" of your state. If you want it to run with the new values, use an `useEffect` hook or pass the current value as an argument.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  // receives the latest value and is called on every change (also the first one!)
}, [value])
```